# How to grayscale image from camera_capture in Rust

Tags: image, rust

completely new in Rust here. I'm trying to make camera fetched image from camera_capture lib (it's based on rscam). When i try to do

```rust
grayscale(&frame)
```

it shows the error like that:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `camera_capture::Frame: DerefMut` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:22:31
   |
22 |         let frame = grayscale(&frame);
   |                               ^^^^^^ the trait `DerefMut` is not implemented for `camera_capture::Frame`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `GenericImage` for `ImageBuffer<Rgb<u8>, camera_capture::Frame>`
```

Here is the complete code:

```rust
 extern crate camera_capture;
 extern crate ncurses;
 extern crate image;
 
 use image::imageops::resize;
 use image::imageops::colorops::grayscale;
 use image::FilterType;
 use image::load_from_memory;
 
 
 
 const ASCII_GREYSCALE: &str = "$@B%8&WM#*oahkbdpqwmZO0QLCJUYXzcvunxrjft/\\|()1{}[]?-_+~<>i!lI;:,\"^`'.";
 
 fn main() {
     let cam = camera_capture::create(0).unwrap();
     let mut cam = cam.fps(30.0).unwrap().start().unwrap();
     let window = ncurses::initscr();
     let mut x: i32 = 0;
     let mut y: i32 = 0;
     ncurses::getmaxyx(window, &mut y, &mut x);
     for frame in cam {
         let frame = grayscale(&frame);                                                                                            
         let frame = resize(&frame, x as u32, y as u32, FilterType::Nearest);
         for (i, pixel) in frame.enumerate_pixels().enumerate() {
             let dupa = pixel.2.data;
             let value = (ASCII_GREYSCALE.len() - 1) * dupa[0] as usize/255 + 1;
             let put_y = (i as i32+1)/x;
             let put_x = i as i32 % x;
             let ch = ASCII_GREYSCALE.chars().rev().nth(value).unwrap() as u32;
             ncurses::mvaddch(put_y, put_x, ch);
         }
         ncurses::refresh();
     }
 }
```

Anybody knows how to convert it to grayscale? Maybe some other library?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i've found the solution. It was possible to convert it to normal image::DynamicImage subtype with:

```rust
let frame = RgbImage::from_raw(frame.width(), frame.height(), frame.to_vec()).unwrap();
```

Then it was possible to:

```rust
grayscale(&frame)
```